# React native expo notification no sound no headup message

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

I have an expo project when trying to use expo push notification it's making  no sound no head-up message 
I receive a notification but without any sound vibration and other msg like other notifications do
I have passed all required parameters like sound:' default' and all.